# c# Binary operation on hex values

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I have a hex value that e.g. following octets: 82 A9 43

I need to remove the 8 bit of all of them and concatenate them together.

e.g.: if we change each to binary:

```
82 = 10000010
A9 = 10101001
43 = 01000011
```

Now I need to remove the MSB on all of the above with the following code:

```
                    int t = 0x7F;
                    int hv1 = 0x82;
                    int hv2 = 0xA9;
                    int hv3 = 0x43;

                    int r1 = hv1 & t;
                    int r2 = hv2 & t;
                    int r3 = hv3 & t;
```

After the above procedure it looks like:

```
r1 = 10
r2 = 101001
r3 = 100011
```

But I need as follows:

```
r1 = 0000010
r2 = 0101001
r3 = 0100011
```

The reason is later I wanted concatenate all the r1 | r2 | r3 to be as follows:

```
000001001010010100011
```

The above should then be converted to integer.

Do you have a clue, how can this be done. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you getting those values? Are you applying a `ToString()` on something?

Comment: The original values I'm getting from a UDP stream. i.e.: 82 A9 43

Comment: I meant how are you getting the binary values? How are converting `r1` to `10` for example?

Comment: IN SNMP WHEN READING FROM THE UDP STREAM:  the 8th MSB bit is the toggle bit, that needs to be stripped off, then the remaining 7 bits should be concatenated with the next bytes. But the octet values I'm using here are examples (82 A9 43) they might be different in the real scenario. But my target is same. Take the OID bytes check if 8th bit is a 1 if yes strip it make it 7 bits and concatenate to the next octet (the next octet will have the same 7 bits with 8th bit stripped off)

Comment: @musefan: I'm anding with 0x7F to remove the 8th bit, but doing so C# removes the leading zero's as well, which I don't want, want to maintain 7 bits for each octet

Comment: It doesn't remove anything! There are no "leading zeros" that is just your representation of the binary value. You are converting it into a string somewhere along the line, and that is what I am asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading 0's on binary values don't really do anything, so you can just count the characters and add the 0's back to the front of them, and then concatenate them together

```
string PadLeft (string s) {
   return string.Format("({0,8})", s)
}
```

Comment: The idea here was these value are coming of the udp stream as hex strings, I want to process them as by removing there most significant bit (to the left) so all the octects have seven bits, then I need to concatenate these 7 bits and get an integer result as shown in the question above

Comment: @user726720 I understand what you are saying but leading zeroes *don't* matter in numbers. `00001 == 1`. Even if you convert to a string and pad the string, then convert back to an integer, C# will just strip off the leading zeros.

Comment: So you want to build a 21 bit integer? If you explain the purpose a little bit, people may be able to give better advice. User Jonesy below gave a pretty good method for padding with zeros though

Comment: That's what I need. I need to keep the leading zero's and make them as 7 bits for each octet and then concatenate them to get the integer value

Comment: @HunterMcMillen but I guess what he's asking would give a different result if you padded the numbers with 0's then concatenated. I guess he could pad with 0's as a string, concatenate as a string, then convert back to an int. It would still strip leading 0's but would give the result he was looking for

Comment: Only for the inner two 7 bit numbers, the leftmost one would still be stripped.

Comment: int result = int.Parse(AddZeros(r1) + AddZeros(r2) + AddZeros(r3));

Comment: @HunterMcMillen sure, but the integer result would be equivalent if he doesn't care about what the binary value of the final result looks like

Comment: @CamHenlin: Please check my comment above on the question.

Comment: @user726720 Padding then concatenating is the only way I can think of that this will work.

Comment: @user726720 yeah, using Hunter McMillen's edit to my post you can get the result you want with: 

int result = int.Parse(PadLeft(r1) + PadLeft(r2) + PadLeft(r3));

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: But using the above how would you determine how many zero's are to be added

Comment: You are stripping off a single bit from each, padding back up to 8 characters would make the leading bit 0 for all 3 bytes. That is what you claim you want.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I guess this should be 0,7 instead of 0,8. As I need to maintain 7 bits and not 8

Comment: This is working, but when I do a (Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt64(resultant)); it gives me the binary value and not integer. I want to convert the binary to integer after the padding and concatenation. Do you have a clue

Comment: Sorry please ignore the above I'm missing the 2 in the above (Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt64(resultant,2)); I guess I need some rest, making silly mistakes

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you are converting your integer values into the binary strings, but I imagine you are doing something like this:

```
string binaryR1 = Convert.ToString(r1, 2);//binaryR1 = "10"
```

You can then pad the string using the `PadLeft()` function:

```
binaryR1 = binaryR1.PadLeft(7, '0');//binaryR1 = "0000010"
```

or in a single line:

```
string binaryR1 = Convert.ToString(r1, 2).PadLeft(7, '0');//binaryR1 = "0000010"
```

NOTE: These values have been padded to 7 digits as you do not require the MSB

Applying this to all 3 values would then allow you to concat into the full string:

```
string full = binaryR1 + binaryR2 + binaryR3;//full = "000001001010010100011"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert to strings then back to integers, just do integer math like this:

```
int concat = r1 << 16 | r2 << 8 | r3;
```

or more briefly:

```
int ttt = 0x7f7f7f; 
int concat = (hv1 << 16 | hv2 << 8 | hv3 & ttt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Numerically, leading zeroes are irrelevant. Have your function return a String representation of the number so you can pad it to 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

if you want them as you've described them, just tack on some zero's to the front, it won't change the binary value

```
private static string AddZeros(string r)
    {
        while (r.Length < 8)
            r = "0" + r;

        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
int r1 = hv1 & 0x7F;
int r2 = hv2 & 0x7F;
int r3 = hv3 & 0x7F;
int res = ( r1 << 14 ) | ( r2 << 7 ) | r3;
```

That should strip the 8th bit of each byte, then concatenate bit 0-7 of each into a 21-bit number:

```
111111122222223333333 // where 1 are bits from r1, 2 from r2 and so on
```

Is that what you wanted?